# Given value in history of time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a way to query data from Oracle.
The idea would be to return values in a given time frame (let's say 2021-01-01 & 2021-12-31).
We have a table that stores all changes historically.

[image]

I am only concerned with up to colum 3 (Org Type) and do not care about what changed beside that column.

In essence, I would like to be able to answer:
What was Org# 8124's Org Type on 2021.01.04. (in which case it would be the latest since it has changed on that day)
Additionally, I since this table only tracks changes, it would need to extend to dates not captured here.
Meaning, for example Org# 18612 has last changed on 2021.01.10. so if someone asks, what was its value on 2021.07.07.(which is not captured in the table) it should be the latest.

I managed to get before&after values with LAG, but I am not sure how to work this out, as again, I need to populate everyday with a value (even tho I don't have that date in the table)
Not sure if it makes any sense. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`lag` and similar will not help, because that only works to compare rows that exist in the data already - not some external date you provide. (You can make it work by adding a row to your data, with the input date and `null` for other columns, using `union all`, and then use `lag` - but it shouldn't be `lag` anyway if your date exists in the data, and in any case it's more complicated than it needs to be.)

Rather, filter the input data by organization id and date, and select the row with the most recent date among those that pass the filter. This last step can be done in many ways (with analytic functions like `row_number`, with aggregate `first/last` function, with `order by` and outer query with filter `rownum=1`, etc.) Since version 12, it's easiest with `fetch ...` as shown below, but that only works if you are working over the entire table (or filter by a single organization, etc.) Otherwise the analytic `row_number` approach is probably best.

So - since I don't have your data - I will use table `employees` in the standard `hr` schema to find the most recent row (newest `hire_date`) on or before 15 December 2006. Instead of "organization id" I filter by `department_id`, and instead of "organization type" I ask for the then-current `job_id`.

```
select department_id, hire_date, job_id
from   hr.employees
where  department_id = 90
  and  hire_date <= date '2006-12-15'
fetch  first row only
;

DEPARTMENT_ID HIRE_DATE   JOB_ID    
------------- ----------- ----------
           90 17-JUN-2003 AD_PRES
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not looking for this scenario. I would need to see what all orgs in my example at all days in the year have uptaken as a value. I would be using to join it to other tables to do some analysis. This would not be an ad-hoc/one-time pull per request where I could just search/filter for a specific date.

Comment: @llorcs - all these additional details about your problem are missing entirely from your question. Perhaps now you understand why it is important to tell us the whole story, not just small fragments from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you store for each change of an entiry a new row with the updat einformation you are basically implementing a [SCD of type 2](http://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row).

To allow more efficient queries with an arbitrary date you may add the (redundant) attribute change_end_d that contains *the last day* on which this change is valid.

This is either the  `LEAD` date of the next change or for the last change of particular key (org_number)  you can use some date in *far future* or  `NULL`.

**Sample Data**

```
ORG_NUMBER CHANGE_D            ORG_TYPE        ADDRESS        
---------- ------------------- --------------- ---------------
      8124 03.01.2021 00:00:00 Customer        Main Street 1  
      8124 04.01.2021 00:00:00 Government      Main Street 1  
     18612 06.01.2021 00:00:00 Undisclosed     Bell Square    
     18612 08.01.2021 00:00:00 Undisclosed     Johnson Ave    
     18612 09.01.2021 00:00:00 Undisclosed     Bell Square    
     18612 10.01.2021 00:00:00 Supplier        Bell Square
```

**Example**

I'm using a view, for large data you may want to use *materialized view* or a table.

```
create view v_hist as 
select 
  org_number,
  change_d,
  lead(change_d,1,DATE'2099-01-01') over (partition by org_number order by change_d) change_end_d,
  org_type,
  address
from hist;
```

The view produces this data

```
ORG_NUMBER CHANGE_D            CHANGE_END_D        ORG_TYPE        ADDRESS        
---------- ------------------- ------------------- --------------- ---------------
      8124 03.01.2021 00:00:00 04.01.2021 00:00:00 Customer        Main Street 1  
      8124 04.01.2021 00:00:00 01.01.2099 00:00:00 Government      Main Street 1  
     18612 06.01.2021 00:00:00 08.01.2021 00:00:00 Undisclosed     Bell Square    
     18612 08.01.2021 00:00:00 09.01.2021 00:00:00 Undisclosed     Johnson Ave    
     18612 09.01.2021 00:00:00 10.01.2021 00:00:00 Undisclosed     Bell Square    
     18612 10.01.2021 00:00:00 01.01.2099 00:00:00 Supplier        Bell Square
```

Using this view you get the data for `18612`  of `2021-07-07` using this query

```
select * from v_hist
where ORG_NUMBER = 18612 and
DATE'2021-07-07' >= CHANGE_D and DATE'2021-07-07' < CHANGE_END_D;
```

**Some Discussion**

- The `CHANGE_END_D` in the last change (though some would argue is should be null) is typically set to some arbitrary high data as it simplifies the data query.
- You may even set the `CHANGE_END_D` *not equel* to the `change_d` of the next version, but a *bit* lower (1 day in your example, 1 second if the change date contains time). Than the query may be further simplified:

.

```
select * from v_hist
where ORG_NUMBER = 18612 and
DATE'2021-07-07' BETWEEN CHANGE_D and CHANGE_END_D;
```

- If you have *frequent changes* it is better to store the *exact* time or the change to avoid the case of multiple changes with the same date without defined order. See your data row 2 and 3.
- Even better is to add a `number`column say `version` that for each org_number defines the *index* of the change 1,2,3...